# How to prove this set as a null set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}^1$, and $\exists q: 0<q<1 $, s.t. for every interval $(a, b)$, there is a sequence of open intervals $\{I_n, n \ge 1 \}$:

$E \cap (a, b) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |I_n|< (b - a) q.$

Prove $m^*(E) = 0.$ (Here $m^*$ means the outer Lebesgue measure.)

In this problem, I tried to prove it by proving $E$ as a uncountable set, but Cantor Set is a counter-example. Then I proved that E has no interval, which means there is no interior points in $E$. However, this cannot help me to prove the initial problem, since the irrational set between $(0,1)$ is another counter-example.

I actually don't know so many ways to prove a set as a null set, so I' m confused.

Comment: It is $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty m^*(I_n) < (b-a)q$ isn't it ?

Comment: Sry! I changed it now.

Comment: @WillieWong does $m^*(E \cap (a, b)) = 0$ really hold for EVERY interval $(a, b)$?

Comment: @Meowdog: I misread $\exists$ for $\forall$, so the question is not as trivial as I thought. But yes: if one can prove that $m^*(E) = 0$, one can prove that $m^*(E\cap (a,b)) = 0$.

Comment: @WillieWongo of course

Comment: The result is immediate if one is willing to bring out the big guns with the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. Below I give a proof that cuts out all the unnecessary parts, but the idea is basically the same as the idea used to prove the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll outline for you how to prove that $E\cap (a,b)$ has outer measure zero for any $(a,b)$. By countable sub-additivity this automatically implies that $E$ has outer measure zero.

The trick is by induction. I claim that for each $k> 0$ there exists a countable collection of open intervals $\{I^{k}_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $E \cap (a,b) \subset \cup_n I^k_n$ and that $\sum_{n} |I^k_n| < (b-a) q^k$.

If the claim is true, then taking $k \to +\infty$ gives you that $m^*(E\cap (a,b))$ has measure zero.

To prove the claim: Suppose $I_n^{k-1}$ has been constructed. For each $n$, apply the hypothesis to find a sequence of intervals $J_m^n$ such that

$$ E \cap I_n^{k-1} = \cup_m J_m^n, \qquad \sum |J_m^n| \leq |I_n^{k-1}| q $$

Since union of countable sets is countable, we have that the set $\{ J^n_m : n,m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable collection of intervals.

Since
$$ E\cap (a,b) \subseteq E \cap \cup I_n^{k-1} = \cup (E\cap I_n^{k-1}) \subseteq \cup_{n} \cup_m J_m^n $$
we have that $\{ J_m^n\}$ covers $E\cap (a, b)$. Finally, we have that
$$ \sum_{n,m} |J_m^n| \leq \sum_{n} |I_n^{k-1}| q \leq q^{k-1} \cdot q = q^k $$

So you can just relabel/enumerate the elements of the countable set $\{J_m^n\}$ as $\{I^k_n\}$.